# How can I turn this row into a link?

Tags: php, html

I want to make that row a link, but I dont know how to add an a href attribute... That row shows information from a DB and I just want to make ir clickeable and not only as plain text. Thank you

This is the row I wanna turn into a link...

```
echo '<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: What should the link point at? What should happen when the user clicks it?

Comment: This is HTML 101 stuff.

Comment: use anchor tag `<a>your link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in an anchor (`a`) tag.

```
echo '<td><a href="/link/to/page">' . $row['nombre'] . '</a></td>';
```

You should also probably take a look at the [W3schools HTML5 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `<a>` to your HTML, and include the URL in it.

```
echo "<td><a href='script.php?id={$row['nombre']}'>{$row['nombre']}</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>
     <a href='yourfile.php?subDom=$row['nombre']'</a>
     </td>";
```

Then you can check for if link is clicked, you can trigger action for click. Like below:

```
if($_GET['whateverComingFromDB'] == "whatDoYouWantToCompare"){
    //...Anything you want to happen after click the link
}
```